# What is wrong with my nginx.conf?

Tags: nginx

Here is my ngnix.conf .

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
}

http {
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; 
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

server {
        listen 8080;
        server_name localhost;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        root /var/www/html;
}
```

To input the command after edited the file.

```
service nginx restart
```

Job for nginx.service failed. See 'systemctl status nginx.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.

```
systemctl -l  status nginx.service 

nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server    
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled)    
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2015-09-16 15:31:14 HKT; 5s ago        
Sep 16 15:31:14 pengsir nginx[6133]: nginx: configuration file 
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

I have fix the problem,new problem remain.

```
nginx -t
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:8080, ignored
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
root@pengsir:/home/debian8# service nginx start
Job for nginx.service failed. See 'systemctl status nginx.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
root@pengsir:/home/debian8# systemctl -l status nginx.service
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2015-09-16 17:37:54 HKT; 21s ago
  Process: 6030 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 9636 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 9634 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 5908 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 16 17:37:51 pengsir nginx[9636]: nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:8080, ignored
Sep 16 17:37:51 pengsir nginx[9636]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 16 17:37:52 pengsir nginx[9636]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 16 17:37:52 pengsir nginx[9636]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 16 17:37:53 pengsir nginx[9636]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 16 17:37:53 pengsir nginx[9636]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8080 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 16 17:37:54 pengsir nginx[9636]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
Sep 16 17:37:54 pengsir systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 16 17:37:54 pengsir systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Sep 16 17:37:54 pengsir systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
```

Comment: Let's clarify: this line:  `service nginx restart` , is it placed at the bottom of your config file?

Comment: `server` should be inside `http` block.

Comment: Also use `nginx -t` to check config. It will tell you exact error and where it occures

Comment: Address already in use means that some program is already listening in that port, tomcat maybe? Try a sudo fuser 8080/tcp to detect which one is

Comment: kill the service ,problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the binding 8080. You need to remove the Binding 8080 from the sites.
Once you remove it restart the service

## service nginx restart

Answer (score 0):

you have another process listening on port 80, in this case httpd. You'll need to stop that service first (and probably want to disable it on boot).

**To stop Apache;**

```
systemctl stop httpd
```

**To stop Apache starting on boot;**

```
systemctl disable httpd
```

**and**

```
proxy_pass https://<IP-OF-YOUR-SERVER>:8443;
```

**for demo**

http://127.0.0.1:8069/web

Answer (score 0):

if (**apache** and **nginx**) have **both**

Do you want to enable Angnix?

**1-systemctl stop httpd**

**2-service nginx restart**

**3-service nginx status**